# How to assign key and values to a dictionary in Python using Lambda function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a dataframe with multiple columns into a dictionary. To do that I first checked if I can access thee values from the dataframe and I was able to do it.

```
>>> dmap = {}
>>> der.show()
+----------+-------------------+
| tablename|incremental_log_ids|
+----------+-------------------+
|db.t1     |                  1|
|db.t2     |                  2|
|db.t3     |                  3|
+----------+-------------------+
>>> der.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).collect()
[('db.t1', '1'), ('db.t2', '2'), ('db.t3', '3')]
```

But when I tried to add the values to a dictionary using a lambda function as below, I don't see the key value pairs inside the dictionary after iteration is completed.

```
>>> def addk(k:str, v:str):
...     dmap[k] = v
...
>>> der.rdd.map(lambda x: addk(x[0], x[1]))
PythonRDD[117] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53
>>>
>>> dmap
{}
```

As it can be seen in the last statement, dmap doesn't show any key value pairs after the iteration is completed.
Could anyone let me know if I have done any mistake here and how can I correct it ?

Comment: so `dmap = dict(der.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])).collect())` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues there. The first problem is that your actions are not running. `map()` doesn't run eagerly (the lazy evaluation in Spark applies here). So you'll need to check `dmap` after running an action, such as count(), collect(), etc.

The second problem is that `map()` runs on workers, but the object into which your expect the values to be added is on the driver. It may happen that `dmap` gets appended to when running locally, but you should not count on that.

An easy implementation could be just a dictionary comprehension on the result of `collect()`:

```
dmap = {r[0]:r[1] for r in der.collect()}
```

Which prints

```
{'db.t1': '1', 'db.t2': '2', 'db.t3': '3'}
```

You need to be careful with this, though, because the data frame may contain too much data to be collected on the driver.